# Plot graph that includes time duration of event as width of bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot different duration entries on a graph, not sure if the best way would be to plot a bar chart and have the duration variable define the width?

The data looks like this:

```
Variable 1     Variable 2     Duration (s)
    50             36            14
    70             41            25
    60             40            20
    55             18            27
```

[image: Duration Plot]

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help out here!

Answer (score 2):

[`plt.step`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) draws a step function of the accumulated time. An extra zero time point and repeating the first entry makes sure all the values are shown.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[50, 36, 14],
        [70, 41, 25],
        [60, 40, 20],
        [55, 18, 27]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Duration'])

xs = df['Duration'].cumsum()

for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    plt.step(np.append(0, xs), np.append(df[col][0], df[col]), where='pre')
plt.xticks(xs, df['Duration'])
plt.yticks(df.iloc[0, :-1], df.columns[:-1])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum` to compute the cumulative duration, then plot with `step`:

```
(df.append(df.iloc[-1])
   .assign(TimeDuration=lambda x: x['Duration (s)'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
   .plot(x="TimeDuration", y=['Variable 1', 'Variable 2'],drawstyle='steps-post')
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you very much. 

If i wanted to plot in different y axis, would that be possible?